# Does autoCommit var resets in c3p0 on close?

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

I am working with DB2. I created ConnectionPool for it. Some of the queries required to be executed in "aumoCommit = false" mode.

```
Connection con = ConnectionPool.getConnection // wrapper
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatment ps = con.prepareStatement(// query... );
ps.setString(...);
ps.executeUpdate();
con.commit();
ps.close();
con.close();
con.setAutoCommit(true); // should be here ?
```

Question is: should i add con.setAutoCommit(true) line in the end or C3P0 resets state of every closed(returned to pool) Connection?

Edit: after a few comments, I add that my question is: should  con.setAutoCommit(false) call be there in general or c3P0 reset state of this connection and nexct time this connection will be in con.setAutoCommit(false) by default?

Comment: Calling `setAutoCommit` after you closed the connection (returned it to the pool) should trigger an exception, as that logical handle should now behave as if it is really closed.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my question is not about where to call setAutoCommit(false), it is more about should I call it in general ?

Comment: A well behaved connection pool should reset a connection to the initial state as if it was a fresh connection as described in the JDBC specification, however not all connection pools do that; not sure about C3P0.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's main question: c3p0 should do it, but does it reset ?

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c3p0 always releases Connections with `autoCommit` set to `true`, per the JDBC spec.

In general, c3p0 endeavors to make it true that nothing you do during an ordinary client session will have any effect on future client sessions. Once a Connection is checked back into the pool, c3p0 fully resets and restores its state.

The only place you can define Connection state that "sticks" across client sessions is in a ConnectionCustomizer's `onAcquire(...)` method, called before any client Session has been initiated. But this only works for Connection attributes whose value is undefined by the JDBC spec. Since `autoCommit` is required by spec to be `true` of a new Connection, and JDBC transparent Connection pooling requires pooled and new Connections be indistinguishable in application semantics, freshly checked-out Connections always have `autoCommit` set to true.